# I can't figure out how to use SOAP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

For the past few days, i,ve been strugleing with SOAP. I can't understand how to properly build the SOAP enveloppe to send to a wsdl web service. I've tried with the functions in php and in node,js and i end up with the same problem.

The problem is : I can reach the server, but it seems i don't send enough info, because the web service always returns false.

Here is the xml structure i need :

```
POST /2010/11/************.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: url.url.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://***********/*******/2010/11/*************/**********"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Function1 xmlns="http://**********.com/*************/2010/11">
      <Function1Request xmlns="http://******.com/********/2010/11">
        <param1>string</param1>
        <param2>string</param2>
      </Function1Request>
    </Function1>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here how i did it in php :

```
<?php
$param1 = 'foo';
$param2 = 'bar';
try
{
 $url =    "https://******.com/2010/11/*******.asmx?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient(¢url,array("trace"=> 1,"exception"=>0,"encoding"=>"UTF-8"));

$params = array(

    "param1" => $param1,
    "param2" => $param2
);
$options = array(
    "SOAPAction" => "http://***********/*******/2010/11/*************/**********",
);
$response = $client->__soapCall("Function1",$params,$options);
var_dump($response);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e;
}
```

Basicly, the web service doesn't process my call and returns false.
Like i said, i did try in node.js as well with the same result.

EDIT : 
This is the answer from the web service :

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'Function1Response' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'IsAuthenticated' => boolean false
      public 'FleetOwnerID' => int 0
```

This is the result of get last request :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://*****.com/services/2010/11">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:Function1/>
               <param1/>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
   </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is my request header :

```
POST /2010/11/*****.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: url.url.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/7.0.15
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://***********/*******/2010/11/*************/**********"
Content-Length: 242
```

And finally, the response header :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 18 May 2017 15:15:20 GMT
Content-Length: 485
```

The request I sent, doesn't look at all like what they ask for. I need help to build it properly.

Comment: There is a typo in this line `$client = new SoapClient(¢url,array("trace"=> 1,"exception"=>0,"encoding"=>"UTF-8"));` it should be `SoapClient($url`

Comment: To help debug your request, you should use `echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";` Posting that in your question would help also. Using `echo "RESPONSE:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";` would also be a good idea. `__getLastRequestHeaders()` and `__getLastResponseHeaders()` could also be helpful. This would make it easy to see the communication between client and server in full.

Comment: Thanks. ill try this, and edit my post

Comment: It was a typo, but it was fine in my code, i just looked.

Answer (score 0):

If you know PHP, then you MUST use a WSDL to php generator to stop struggling so much. Use the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project and it should become crystal clear.